# Firebase Analytics Debug View is connected, but not showing events

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics, debugview

I have an app in Xcode that is connected to Firebase / Firebase Debugger. I have previously connected the app to the debugger and it was working (using -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled). I then turned the debugger off, using -FIRDebugDisabled.

I now am trying to reconnect to the debugger. I have turned off -FIRDebugDisabled and I have tried using both -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled and -FIRDebugEnabled. The debugger shows that the simulator is connected and I receive the following print (Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: screen_view...) in XCode. HOWEVER, the events are not showing in Firebase Debug View. How do I get them to show in the Debug View?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue and none of the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373948/firebase-ios-debug-console-not-logging-anything helped.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your GoogleService-Info.plist file if **IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED** property is true.
[image]

Comment: This property is irrelevant, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38559614/2779681