# Unable to view Firebase Analytics Debug View React Native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I've followed multiple tutorials and read multiple Stackoverflow posts, but no matter what I do, I can't get anything to show up in my DebugView for my iOS app using RNFireBase. I would really appreciate some help with this. I've lost days trying to figure this out and I have no idea what is wrong. I tried on both a simulator and a physical device and no luck with either.

I'm getting logging messages to show up in my console in XCode, but nothing shows up in the Firebase Console. Here are the messages I get locally when using an event:

### React Native

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>
    analytics().logSelectContent({
      content_type: "clothing",
      item_id: "abcd",
    })
  }
>
  <Text>Log message</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

### Logs

```
2020-05-15 12:22:26.486761-0400 Example App[23464:8820959] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: app, select_content, {
    content_type = clothing;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = UIViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -3307323385789565728;
    item_id = abcd;
}
2020-05-15 12:22:26.487676-0400 Example App[23464:8820959] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: select_content, {
    content_type = clothing;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = UIViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -3307323385789565728;
    item_id = abcd;
}
2020-05-15 12:22:26.500453-0400 Example App[23464:8820959] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: select_content, {
    content_type = clothing;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = UIViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -3307323385789565728;
    item_id = abcd;
}
2020-05-15 12:22:26.502567-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 0.9828788042068481
2020-05-15 12:22:26.502616-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 0.9828788042068481
2020-05-15 12:22:27.497172-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
2020-05-15 12:22:27.497304-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
2020-05-15 12:22:27.497444-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023033] Starting data upload
2020-05-15 12:22:27.501020-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: select_content, {
    content_type = clothing;
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = UIViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -3307323385789565728;
    item_id = abcd;
}
2020-05-15 12:22:27.511485-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 499
2020-05-15 12:22:27.512391-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 38, 1589559746485
2020-05-15 12:22:27.518879-0400 Example App[23464:8821128] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023038] Uploading events. Elapsed time since last successful upload (s): 44.21102094650269
2020-05-15 12:22:27.519180-0400 Example App[23464:8820960] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1589559747518, <APMPBMeasurementBatch: 0x2808513f0>
2020-05-15 12:22:27.524885-0400 Example App[23464:8820960] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2020-05-15 12:22:27.607462-0400 Example App[23464:8820960] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2020-05-15 12:22:27.674761-0400 Example App[23464:8821408] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
2020-05-15 12:22:27.679982-0400 Example App[23464:8821408] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.1942161321640015
2020-05-15 12:22:27.680071-0400 Example App[23464:8821408] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): -0.1942161321640015
2020-05-15 12:22:27.688291-0400 Example App[23464:8821408] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled
2020-05-15 12:22:27.688364-0400 Example App[23464:8821408] 6.13.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
```

### Here's everything I've done:

#### I modified my `AppDelegate.m`

```
// imports
#import <Firebase.h> // Imported Firebase.h
// more imports

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
        [FIRApp configure];
    }
// ... rest of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

#### I added GoogleService-Info.plist to my app target. I then followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352833/6942666) and:

> Now it doesn't matter much but still for the people who are getting errors on this issue. Debug mode of firebase analytics does not work sometimes due to issue in GoogleServices-Info.plist file Simply makes these 2 changes.
>
> Set IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED to YES
>
> Set FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATE to NO

[image]

#### Removing `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` entirely

I then removed `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` from my .plist like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370967/6942666) suggested. Still not working.

#### Made sure there was no `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE:disable` enabled like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913609/6942666) said

> Make sure to remove the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE:disable from the Environment Variables in your project scheme if you added it at some point.

#### Set environment variables

[image]

#### Podfile.lock relevant section

```
- Firebase/Analytics (6.13.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Core (6.13.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.1.6)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.13.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.4.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.6):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.4)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.1.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - FirebaseCore (6.4.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.2)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.2.4):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 3.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.7):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.0)
```

Comment: Hi what is the module you use to integrate the firebase services for you react-native app

Comment: RNFirebase @EL173

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with RNFirebase. But I'm suggesting you to react-native-firebase instead for RNFirebase if possible, cause it has very good documentation+community. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Comment: @EL173 sorry my mistake. I meant react-native-firebase. I've been staring at my Podfile for so long the podfile rnfirebase came to mind first

Comment: Okay then in which version are you ?

Comment: @EL173 7.0.1 for both @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/analytics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213961/discussion-between-el173-and-eric-wiener).

Comment: In case anyone else sees this post, this has still not been resolved

Comment: I am in the same boat... Debug works on android and in Xcode console I can see just like yours that the Firebase Analytics events are firing but they never show in the debug view :(

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Was never able to figure it out unfortunately. Ended up just dropping Firebase for the time being

Comment: @EricWiener , I thought I have the problem exactly the same you. I am trying to figure it out about 8 hours already. But still nothing source important to look.  em.. :( . This is just happen only react-native?

Comment: @LeangSocheat I only attempted to use it with react-native, so not sure

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by

1. Setting Environment Variable as you did with -FIRDebugEnabled.
2. Rather than running the application in react native (ex: yarn run ios/android), I directly run in Xcode. (If you run through react native, it doesn't appear in debug view for me as well).
3. Then magically the device will appear in Debug View. I haven't followed through any other steps that you've mentioned.[image]

Here are my versions just in case. If it hasn't be resolved, hope it helps a little.

```
"react-native": "^0.63.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.7",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.9",
```

Comment: Wow... spent hours going through all the above but no dice until this little piece of advice. Thank you!

Comment: Didn’t get a chance to test this, but judging by the upvotes I’ll assume it works. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

So after hours of reading and testing, I figure I will leave this note here for anyone wondering if their setup is actually working.

As the other answer suggested: Run your app via Xcode with the debug flags instead of through the terminal but also **monitor the debug output console for firebase related messages.**

Mine seems to be actually working and yours might be as well. One thing I also discovered is that they 'batch' the events and it took a solid hour or so after you put the application in the background for the events to come through to the firebase console debug view.

[image: Xcode debug console output]

[image: Debug devices]